# Quanteda problems in R

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I am using Quanteda in R and have created the corpus and dfm. However, I notice that the dfm and corpus contain less documents than the original file. I would appreciate if anyone could please let me know why this happens and how to fix? Thanks

Comment: Hey! welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some context (e.g., code). It's difficult to help fix a problem if we don't know what is causing it :p

Answer (score 0):

You can try mention the `docid_field` and `text_field` explicitly something like this:

```
data_corpus = corpus(x = data,docid_field = "doc_id", text_field = "text")
```

where `doc_id` and `text` are columns in the dataframe `data`.

And then compute the Document Feature Matrix using `dfm` function of `qunateda` package

```
data_dfm = dfm(data_corpus)
```